# Generate Pie Chart with Python with already existing data from Excel without overwriting the Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pie-chart

I'm new to Pandas and Data frames and all of this and I've been trying to generate some charts (pie charts to be exact) with data that is already in an Excel file.

I have one worksheet which contains a big chunk of data. From that worksheet, using openpyxl I'm generating a new worksheet where I add some formulas to return some values looking like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojM2R.png

Contents here as well:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| User  |  Total  | Open  | Closed | Fixed |Rejected |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| James    23        7       16        7       12    |
| Michael  2         1       1         1       0     |
| Andreas  11        7       4         3       3     |
| Betty    6         2       4         1       3     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

What I want to do now is generate a pie chart with Users and each of the other columns (one pie chart User X Total Tickets, one pie chart with User X Open Tickets and so on)

I've tried xlsxwritter but it overwrites my whole document and didn't manage to have it working.
All of the examples with openpyxl which won't overwrite my document contain randomly generated data, not already existing data from and Excel file, and I don't know how to implement those methods with what I want to do.

Can you please help me understand what I should do and maybe how?

I was also wondering if the is a way, like a formula, to generate a pie chart. Something like

`(=PIECHART(Sheet!B1:B5,Sheet!C1:C5))`.

Thanks a bunch,
Cheers,
Alin

Comment: Could you put the contents of the worksheet directly in your question? External links may disappear, which would make it hard to follow for someone later reading this.

Comment: @PirateNinjas I don't know how to insert the table but I've tried to make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df.set_index('User').T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(15,10), layout=(2,2))
plt.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

## Update:

```
df.set_index('User').plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(15,10), layout=(2,3))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Scott. Thanks for answering. This is not exactly want I needed but I'll try and change it to what I need. I need plots for each state of ticket x user. A plot for Open Tickets which will show how many open tickets each of the users have. Was also wondering if Excel charts could be generated to be saved somewhere on the sheet containing the table as well.